# Formal Description Of Data Structure For Infinite Sets Of Reals

Tags: data-structures, reference-request, sets

The paper I'm working on uses sets as implemented in https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html. A set is stored in a data structure as a sequence of intervals with open or closed bounds, so it can represent uncountable and infinite sets. What prior work can I reference for this data structure?

Comment: Related to https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69830/what-is-the-name-of-this-positive-integer-set-data-structure but for Reals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to reference any prior work; it's a basic enough approach.  You can just say that you represent a set as a union of intervals.  If you were inspired by Sympy, you could cite Sympy and that page.

Comment: What about algorithms on the data structure, like union and intersection and complement?

Comment: @Brent, those seem straightforward to me if those are the only operations you need to support.  You can also look at segment trees and interval trees.  [Interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) have the benefit of additionally supporting efficient stabbing queries.